# Can we declare constructor before member variables?

Tags: c++

Can the constructer declared before the member variable alter its value?

I thought only the code below works,

```
struct test {
    int a; 
    test(int t): a(t) {}
};
```

but I found the code below also works.

```
struct test {
    test(int t): a(t) {}
    int a; 
};
```

Usually, in function, we cannot use the variable that is not declared. Why the code above is OK?

Comment: @273K It is not the fact that it's `inline` that saves it! `inline int foo() { return a; } int a;` doesn't work (at global level). There is simply an exception made for classes: the definitions of constructors and functions inside the class body are interpreted in the "complete class context" (the context right after the closing `}` of the class) instead of at their syntactic position.

Comment: More specifically: The inside of a member function body is a [complete-class context](https://eel.is/c++draft/class#mem.general-7). It's a bit of an unusual situation in C++ which usually goes top to bottom, or at least requires an explicit forward declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually in C++ there's an exception that there's no need for forward declaration of functions and variable of a class/struct.

You can see my such examples on the internet like this:

```cpp
class foo
{
public:
    foo(int x) : my_var(x) {}
private:
    int my_var;
};
```

The above is 100% valid.

You can also call a function of a class before it is defined like:

```cpp
class bar
{
public:
    bar() 
    {
        this->my_below_func();
    }

    int my_below_func()
    {
        return 1;
    }
};
```

Always remember that these tricks aren't going to work outside C++ classes/structs, you will need *forward declaration* of your functions and variables.